# Capitalisation for emphasis?

Tags: grammaticality, capitalization, descriptive-grammar, titles, headline-case

Let's say we have a time card software system. In the help FAQ, is the second version grammatically correct, or preferable?

> How can we locate time cards that had errors?
>
> How can we locate Time Cards that had errors?

Our younger (early twenties) UX guy delivered us FAQ mock-ups with quite a lot of non-standard capitalisation and we are trying to figure out if we need to de-capitalize some words.

For example, the last FAQ says:

> What if I still have a Question?

Comment: This is not about grammar. It's about Style. You can do as you like as long as you are consistent and your readers approve.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the person who wrote this software was educated in Germany. The German custom is to capitalise all nouns. That is exactly what has happened in these questions - only the nouns are capitalised except, of course, the initial words of the sentence.

Or this could be an automatic (or misguided) translation from German which has retained the capitalisation of the source language.

Answer (score 0):

From:

https://www.searchenginejournal.com/best-faq-page-examples/267709/#close

it seems most organisations use sentence-case for FAQ questions.

One used all-caps, which can avoid the issue.